# Plotly Dash - how to set automated colors rather than having blue for everything

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm looking to get help in creating a bar chart in Dash (plotly) and having more than one color for all bars,at the moment they are all blue.

e.g.

```
    pv = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['customer_name2'], columns=['FY'], values=['amount'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
    pv2 = pv.reindex(pv['amount'].sort_values(by='FY17', ascending=True).index).head(x_bottom)
    trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv2.index, y=pv2[('amount','FY17')], name='Revenue')

    graphs.append(html.Div(dcc.Graph(
    id='chart_id_6',
    figure={
        'data': [trace1],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'Bottom ' + str(x_bottom) + ' Customers'
        }
    })))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a list of colors, with a different color for each Bar.

```
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=pv2.index, 
    y=pv2[('amount','FY17')], 
    name='Revenue',
    marker=dict(
        color=['rgba(204,204,204,1)', 
               'rgba(222,45,38,0.8)',
               ...])
)
```

See https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/ chapter: Customizing Individual Bar Colors

This might also help: [Different colors for bars in barchart by their value](https://community.plot.ly/t/different-colors-for-bars-in-barchart-by-their-value/6527/2)

Answer (score 0):

For json format below code will work :

```
graphs.append(html.Div(dcc.Graph(
    id='chart_id_6',
    figure={
        'data': [{'x':pv2.index, 'y': pv2[('amount','FY17')],
                  'marker': {'color': ['#b50000', '#e63535', '#fa8989']}}],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'Bottom ' + str(x_bottom) + ' Customers'
        }
    })))
```